# Populating HTML with value fetched from AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have an update button and on clicking it should give me values of the particular user. For this I have the following piece of code.

HTML Button:

```
<button onclick="return getUserDetails(<? echo $user['id']; ?>)" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".update-modal">Update</button>
```

In the following function I'm obtaining the details of the user.

Javascript Function:

```
function getUserDetails(userId, compId) {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<? echo base_url(); ?>user/get_user_details", 
    data: {userId: userId,
           compId: compId
          },
        success: function(data){
          var text = JSON.parse(data); 
          console.log(text[0]);
        }
});
}
```

I want the above obtained user details to be populated in the following fields.

HTML Modal Code:

```
<div class="modal fade update-modal">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Update User</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email" class="sr-only">User First Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="userFName" id="userFName" value="" placeholder="User First Name"/>
    </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="updateUser()">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div><!-- /.modal-content -->
```

However I'm not able to obtain the desired result. Can someone help me?

Console.log is giving me the correct result however when I use document.write or innerHTML I do not see any values at all.

Comment: What result do you get, what error messages do you see, what happens, what doesn't?

Comment: Hi Markus, I'm sorry. I have updated my question with the same.

Comment: If you successfully retrieve the details from the server and can see it in the browsers console, then what is the question? Take each detail and use javascript to place it inside the target elements in your html markup. Or do you get a complete html markup back from the server?

Comment: @arkascha I have updated my question. I'm not able to place it in target elements. It gives me an empty value.

Comment: Please post what exactly you get back from the server. And also how you try to place it in your page.

Comment: Is the php script returning any value ? also set, `datatype : "application/json",` to the ajax request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone. I sorted out the issue. I added the following changes to my code.

```
document.getElementById('user_f_name').value  = text[0].user_fname;
document.getElementById('user_l_name').value  = text[0].user_lname;
document.getElementById('user_email').value   = text[0].user_name;
document.getElementById('user_role').value    = text[0].user_role;
```